# Keras style lossless triplet loss

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to replicate the [lossless tripler loss](https://towardsdatascience.com/lossless-triplet-loss-7e932f990b24), but using the "K." syntax, like in my triplet loss below:

**My code**

```
def triplet_loss_01(y_true, y_pred, alpha = 0.2):

  total_lenght = y_pred.shape.as_list()[-1]
  print("triplet_loss.total_lenght: ", total_lenght)

  anchor = y_pred[:,0:int(total_lenght*1/3)]
  positive = y_pred[:,int(total_lenght*1/3):int(total_lenght*2/3)]
  negative = y_pred[:,int(total_lenght*2/3):int(total_lenght*3/3)]

  pos_dist = K.sum(K.square(anchor-positive),axis=1)

  neg_dist = K.sum(K.square(anchor-negative),axis=1)

  basic_loss = pos_dist-neg_dist+alpha
  loss = K.maximum(basic_loss,0.0)

  return loss
```

**Code from the article**

```
def lossless_triplet_loss(y_true, y_pred, N = 3, beta=N, epsilon=1e-8):

    anchor = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred[:,0:N])
    positive = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred[:,N:N*2]) 
    negative = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred[:,N*2:N*3])

    # distance between the anchor and the positive
    pos_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor,positive)),1)
    # distance between the anchor and the negative
    neg_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor,negative)),1)

    #Non Linear Values  

    # -ln(-x/N+1)
    pos_dist = -tf.log(-tf.divide((pos_dist),beta)+1+epsilon)
    neg_dist = -tf.log(-tf.divide((N-neg_dist),beta)+1+epsilon)

    # compute loss
    loss = neg_dist + pos_dist

    return loss
```

As I unterstand, all I have to do is to insert

```
pos_dist = -tf.log(-tf.divide((pos_dist),beta)+1+epsilon)
neg_dist = -tf.log(-tf.divide((N-neg_dist),beta)+1+epsilon)
```

in my code. Is there a "translation" from "tf." style to "K." style for these lines?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way you can do:

```
VECTOR_SIZE = 10 # set it to value based on your model

def lossless_triplet_loss(y_true, y_pred, N = VECTOR_SIZE, beta=VECTOR_SIZE, epsilon=1e-8):

    anchor = y_pred[:,0:N]
    positive = y_pred[:,N:2*N]
    negative = y_pred[:,2*N:]

    # distance between the anchor and the positive
    pos_dist = K.sum(K.square(anchor - positive),axis=1)

    # distance between the anchor and the negative
    neg_dist = K.sum(K.square(anchor - negative),axis=1)

    # some magic
    pos_dist = -K.log(-((pos_dist) / beta)+1+epsilon)
    neg_dist = -K.log(-((N-neg_dist) / beta)+1+epsilon)

    loss = neg_dist + pos_dist

    return loss
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. The only thing is y_pred is not [10], but [256] (size of a batch), so I changed this part. All I am trying to do is to push clusters (of MNIST or anything else, doesn't mater) to be more compact and further from each other. So far no luck : Triplet loss works for MNIST, but clusters are overlapping. Somewhere in the net I saw an article about using distances to clusters' centroids - can not find. Not this one (https://github.com/popcornell/keras-triplet-center-loss/blob/master/triplet.py) - it has same tf. to K. problem :) But a detailed one, with theory...

Comment: For me also, lossless variation of triplet loss did worse than normal triplet loss. I used it for a similar use case, have you tried the normal triplet loss ?

Comment: I tried a "normal" one. Clasters for MNIST are overlaping a bit, so I was looking for a way to create a distance between them and in the same time, to avoid pulling them all in one point. As for the code above, it gets to infinity due to log's behaviour :(